# How to cache in sharepoint 2010 based on login user

Tags: caching, sharepoint-2010

I need to store dynamically created xmldatasource for menu in cache based on the login user. The below code is returning the same data for all the users since i did not mentioned the login user. where do I need to mention the login name while add a cache? also i want to reset or remove the cache while add a new site from event receiver since sitemap has to recreate.

```
    private static object _lock = new object();

    public XmlDocument CacheData()
    {            
        XmlDocument item;
        lock (_lock)
        {
            item = (XmlDocument)Cache["SiteMapCache"];
            if (item == null)
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                {
                    SPWebApplication webapp = site.WebApplication;
                    item = GenerateMenu(webapp);
                }
                Cache.Add("SiteMapCache",
                    item, null,
                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
                    System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                    System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default,
                    null);
            }
            return item;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

one Not sure why you would be doing this. As if you built a Sharepoint OOTB publishing site, additional sub site's which a user had access to would appear. If you went down the root of caching each you could end up with loads of entries in the cache, as each one would need to be different.

Else add the USERName to the CacheKey name.

Then change your code so it first checks to see if the "SiteMapCache"+Spcontext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.name is null, if it is fetch it and store it as cache.

You will need another cached item, to store a list of users who have been added to the cache.

Then if a new site is created, loop through each one and set cached item to null.